# обработка ошибок file_get_contents (out of memory)

Tags: php

Есть скрипт, который качает файлы по ссылкам из excel файла.

```
try {
   $file = file_get_contents(trim($link));
}
catch (Exception $e) {
   debug("{$filepath}/{$info['filename']}}"."\n");
   echo("{$filepath}/{$info['filename']}}"."\n");
   $file = fopen("{$filepath}/{$info['filename']}}".".txt", "w");
   $direct_link = trim($link);
   fwrite($file, $direct_link);
   fclose($file);
   continue;
}
file_put_contents("{$filepath}/{$info['filename']}.{$info['extension']}", $file ?: 'Ошибка');
```

Все работает отлично, но в какой то момент попадаются тяжелые для php файлы и ему не хватает памяти.

```
Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 322961408) (tried to allocate 213909528 bytes) in C:\Users\user\IdeaProjects\getfiles\getFiles.php on line 63
```

`ini_set("memory_limit", "1000M")` выставил память, тоже не помогает.
Почитал в интернете и понял, что эта функция не предназначена для больших файлов.

Хочу обработать эту ошибку, если лезет такая ошибка, то качать файл не надо, а надо всего лишь создать текстовый документ и записать ссылку на этот файл в него и идти дальше. Но что-то не выходит, `try` `catch` не отрабатывает. Хотя есть подозрение, что я очень плохо разбираюсь в теме и `fatal error` не отлавливаются и ничего не поделать.

Все делаю локально, без серверов, и решил бы сервер проблему?
Файлы не гигабайтные, около 150-200 метров.

Comment: phpinfo() выводит memory_limit => 2048 => 128M , т.е не меняется

Answer (score 0):

Продолжить работу после Out of memory нельзя. Fatal error - это [ошибка настолько фатальная](https://phpdelusions.net/articles/error_reporting#fatal), что после неё можно сделать очень немного. Разве что в файл записать. Но и то - для каких-то осмысленных действий надо сначала освободить занятую память, а это значит что перед началом работы скрипта надо [сначала эту память занять](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/HandleExceptions.php#L37). В общем, морока ещё та.

Другое дело что проблема обычно решается по-другому.

- Во-первых, совершением осмысленных действий. Если качаемый файл действительно имеет размер не больше 200 метров, то и объем памяти, которую займет скрипт, будет не больше 200 метров. А - Арифметика. То есть если у тебя памяти расходуется больше, это значит что ты ее чем-то забил. Вот и надо освободить. Например чтение ссылок из экселя это примерно как экскаватором насыпать сахар в чай. Возьми начала выгрузи все ссылки в текстовый файлик. А потом уже читай из него.
- Во-вторых, надо следить за памятью, возможно она тупо где-то течет - ты занимаешь память под какую-то переменную, но не освобождаешь её и переменные копятся, занимая память. Это вроде не твой случай, но всегда надо иметь в виду.
- Ну и в-последних, если больше ничего не помогает, надо убедиться, что увеличение memory_limit действительно сработало. В данном случае у тебя какие-то совсем бессвязные цифры - уже занято 300М, пытаешься добавить 200М, а лимит по пхпинфо - 2000М. Что-то где-то не так.

Comment: Добрый день.Спасибо за советы , особенно за экскаватор и сахар , очень наглядно и доходчиво )

Answer (score 0):

```
   copy(trim($link), "{$filepath}/{$info['filename']}.{$info['extension']}");
```

Как узнал , get_file_contents очень памятно-затратная вещь и лучше использовать copy(). Мне помогло